# VirtualTreeView component for XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, virtualtreeview

Where can I get a VirtualTreeView component for Delphi XE2?
I can see the download for VirtualTreeView as the top link here:
http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=30&Itemid=35

But there's no package for Delphi XE2 and the installer does not support XE2.
The source only package only supports up to Delphi 2007 (which is pre Unicode).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the link for SVN checkout: http://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/source/checkout

Comment: I Cant Download From Code.Google.Com Last Virtual-TreeView Source. What I can to do.

Comment: @mehdilotfi - You should use SVN client and type `svn checkout http://virtual-treeview.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ virtual-treeview-read-only` (http://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/source/checkout) You will have `svn` command when you install for instance http://tortoisesvn.net/

Answer (score 6):

You must go to the code google site http://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/ of the `virtual-treeview` the Delphi-XE2 packages was added in the [revision 312](http://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/source/detail?r=312)

Comment: Note that this is still VCL-only.  There is no FireMonkey version of VirtualTreeView as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SVN and get the latest project source code.

As mentioned on 
http://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/source/checkout

> Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over
>   HTTP. svn checkout http://virtual-treeview.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
>   virtual-treeview-read-only

If you are using Tortoise SVN its easy to set a folder on your system that can always be easily updated to the latest version.
http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html

Comment: Apologies to Pol somehow missed seeing your post.